# UIAlertView does not display on iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have created a generalized method method to display an alertview.  I have appended my code for review.
I am trying to validate three uitextfields and if invalid, put relevant information in instance variables used in the uialertview method.  You can see that I have plenty of nslog statements sprinkled thru the code.  The nslogs at the beginning and end of the method all display relevent information for the error that occurred.  When I click on the button in the Simulator screen that sets this in motion, there is no message displayed but the screen background, it is light gray, will change to a darker gray.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)SendErrorMessage
{
    NSLog(@"Starting SendErrorMessage");
    NSLog(@"initWithTitle = %@", self.alertViewTitleText);
    NSLog(@"message = %@", self.alertViewMessageText);
    NSLog(@"cancelButtonTitle = %@", self.alertViewCancelButtonText);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                         initWithTitle:self.alertViewTitleText
                         message:self.alertViewMessageText
                         delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                         self.alertViewCancelButtonText
                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Finished SendErrorMessage");
    return;

}
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

OK,

I am really confused now.  I went into the code and added the following code just below the [alert show]:
// Block for 5 seconds
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];

I did this to see if the alertview was actually being displayed to fast to be seen.  Nope, based on my log the program sat for 5 seconds and then continued on with the program logic.  I also replaced the uialertview with
an uiactionsheet to see if it would display where the uialertview doesn't.  Once again, nope, neither of them will display on the simulator screen.

Here is my interface statement in my .h file:
    @interface BeginningScene : UIViewController, 
    (less than)UIActionSheetDelegate, 
    UITextViewDelegate, 
    UIAlertViewDelegate(greater than)

Again, thanks for the assistance and any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you print out your NSLogs

Comment: Does your app crash at this point? alert views are presented over a semi-transparent background (which is lighter in the middle of the screen), so this sounds as if this background is shown but the actual alert view itself is not, which could be because the app crashes at that point.

Comment: Are you sure the method is called from the main thread ? Anyway you might want to put the UIAlert part of the code to run on the main thread so that the method might be called from the background thread and the alert still works.

Comment: Start with something real simple. In the frontmost view controller try to show a 'Hello World' alert. If that works then try your class at the same point in the view controller. That will tell you where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is running on main thread ?
Try using this when you call sendErrorMessage

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sendErrorMessage)];
```

Skip the return statement, it is of no use.

Anyway, try this code and copy the method to your header file as well, note the lower case S, just a preference.

```
- (void)sendErrorMessage
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Title"
                      message:@"message"
                      delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:
                      @"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release]; // if you are not using ARC
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that when an uialertview was executed that it paused the execution of the app until a reply is entered by the user.  That appears not to be the case. The app immediately does a segue to another scene and abends.  Maybe the app doesn't have time to finish the uialertview before the app abends.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following in the class that will display the UIAlertView (.h header file):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And then, in the .m implementation, setting the delegate to `self` when you create the UIAlertView:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle:self.alertViewTitleText
                     message:self.alertViewMessageText
                     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:
                     self.alertViewCancelButtonText
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I recently found out that uialertview does not pause the application until the user responds.  After the uialertview is executed, the program immediately performs a segue to another scene and abends.  It might be that the app doesn't have time to complete the uialertview before the app abends.